# disabledAlgorithms 'DH keySize < 2048' ignored

Tags: tls, diffie-hellman

I have a JBoss application running on openjdk version "1.8.0_212" where I can influence the security settings via the java.security file. However, using this line:
`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL`
the server still allows DH 1024 as shown by nmap:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -Pn -p 14335 <IP redacted>
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-06 18:27 CEST
Nmap scan report for <name redacted> (<IP redacted>)
Host is up (0.053s latency).

PORT      STATE SERVICE
14335/tcp open  unknown
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Key exchange (dh 1024) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.85 seconds
```

I found out that I can list each of the DHE cipher suites in the disabledAlgorithms, and then they are not usable anymore. But why does 'DH < 2048' not have the effect of requiring at least DH 2048? Is it the old java version (that is not under my control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's probably just nmap.**

If I test with a simple Java server (not Jboss) in both 8u212 and more recent (8u321), it *does* prevent a connection using DHE-1024, but on second flight not first. Specifically

1. client sends ClientHello offering DHE suites (in 1.2 or below, because 1.3 no longer uses suites for keyexchange)
2. server agrees to DHE and (by default) sends 1024-bit parameters and server key
3. client (not updated to require 2048-bit) sends client key which is necessarily also 1024-bit
4. server detects violation of size constraint and aborts with alert 40, before CCS and Finished and thus before any data

Although I haven't (and won't) read through the code of nmap, given its goal of analyzing a large number of possible suites rapidly, I suspect it only looks at step 2 and sees the 1024-bit parameters, and either ignores or more likely skips the rest of the handshake. But using `openssl s_client -debug` I can clearly see where the handshake fails as well as seeing the exception and lack of connection on the server side.

If you want to disable DHE to avoid using these inadequate parameters, instead of listing all the suites in disabledAlgorithms you can simply put the underlying *algorithm* `DHE`. However, if you want to support adequate DHE (by current standards 2048 or higher) you need to change *step 2* (not 4) by configuring in j8 up *sysprop* `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize`; see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502672/how-to-expand-dh-key-size-to-2048-in-java-8
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353025/java-jvm-hotspot-ephemeraldhkeysize
and as linked in the former https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#customizing_dh_keys except you can normally ignore the parts about export suites because those have been disabled (by default) since 8u51 in 2015.

Comment: The original report was brought up by Qualys scanner that issued the weak DH key exchange alert. I just found nmap quicker to test it, but what you say makes sense, and maybe qualys also skips part of the handshake. Using the JDK sysprop works and changes the nmap output to `dh 2048`. However I ended up disabling `DH` which seems to have the same effect as `DHE`.

Comment: @8dot42: in disabledAlgos DH includes all three pre-1.3 keyexchanges DHE DH_anon static-DH, and in practice no one uses the latter two so yes it is effectively the same as disabling DHE. And given nearly everything today supports ECDHE which is better anyway, and maybe 1.3 which forces min 2048 for FFDHE if implemented at all (which it sometimes? often? isn't), junking 1.2-style DHE entirely is usually sensible even though you didn't quite ask that :-)